# Unable to add an item inline via a search screen

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Lightswitch Beta 1 to create a simple application.  I'm trying to create a search screen for a table that contains an `Int32` filed called `ID` and a `String` field called `Name`.

If I customize my search screen and try to add an `Add...` button to my command bar of the datagrid, when I go to use the search screen and click `Add...`, I will get a pop-up windows that allows me to successfully add a new item by typing some text into the `Description` field.

I also tried to customize my search screen by adding an `Add` button (the `Add...` button uses a pop-up screen while the `Add` button is supposed to let you save in-line) to the command bar of the datagrid.  However, when I use the search screen and click the `Add` button on the command bar, I see a new line show up with a `*`, but I'm not able to type text into the `Description` box.  Therefore, I'm not able to use the in-line `Add` button to add data to a search screen. Is this normal?

Is there something I need to do to be able to successfully use the `Add` button to add an in-line entry for a search screen in Lightswitch?